# How to combine datatable search box and tableTools buttons in one row

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using datatable tableTools multiple rows selection (Select/Deselect All) using below example.

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/select_multi.html

I want to combine Search box and Select/Deselect All buttons in one row only. Currently Select/Deselect All is in one row and Search box is in another down to it and consuming two rows, I want to optimize the space so that it will be in single row.

This is how it looks like currently:

[image: example how it looks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="DTTT_container" id="chuji1" ><a class="DTTT_button DTTT_button_text" id="ToolTables_example_0" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example"><span>Select all</span></a><a class="DTTT_button DTTT_button_text DTTT_disabled" id="ToolTables_example_1" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example"><span>Deselect all</span></a></div>

<div id="example_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>Search:<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="example"></label></div>![enter image description here][1]


step 1: put these two css classes in library

.cssforchuji1{position: absolute;padding-left: 804px;padding-top:5px;}
.cssforchuji2{padding-right: 243px;}

step 2: put this code in js

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#chuji1").addClass('cssforchuji1');
    $("#example_filter").addClass('cssforchuji2');
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it worked fine. However had to use !important in front of `position:absolute` as `position:relative` is already defined in TableTools css